# Occasional null pointer exception on jsp form (java Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

I saw some NullPointerExceptions in the log. All the exceptions are from two users. The spring controller is supposed to received the form object that the user uploaded. However it is null.

This is the jsp code of the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/events/${id}/tickets/checkout" id="checkout-info-form">

                                    <label> Recipient Name <input id="recipient" type="text" name="recipient"></label>

                                    <label class="address-row checkout-hidable"> Address Line 1 <input id="address1" type="text" name="addressLine1"> </label>
                                    <label class="checkout-hidable"> Address Line 2 (optional) <input id="address2" type="text" name="addressLine2"> </label>
                                    <label class="city-row checkout-hidable"> City <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="e.g. New York"> </label>
                                    <label class="state-row checkout-hidable"> State <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="e.g. NY"> </label>
                                    <label class="zip-row checkout-hidable">  Zip Code <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="e.g. 12345"> </label>
                                    <label class="shipping-row">Shipping Method:</label>
                                    <label class="shipping-method">
                                       <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="usps_5days" id="shipping1">
                                       <span>USPS 3-5 days shipping</span> $5.99
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="shipping-method">
                                       <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="usps_1days" id="shipping2">
                                       <span>USPS overnight shipping</span> $19.99
                                    </label>
                                    <c:set var="index" value="${0}"/>
                                    <c:forEach items="${tickets}" var="ticket">
                                       <input type="hidden" name="tickets[${index}]" value="${ticket.id}">
                                       <c:set var="index" value="${index + 1}"/>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                    <c:remove var="index"/>
                                    <input id="checkout-info-form-submit-button" class="btn-blue-large" type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Next step">
                                </form>
```

This is the model object that I use to receive the form:

```
public class CheckoutInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2585075011792338943L;
    private String recipient;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String shipping;
    private String[] tickets;

    public CheckoutInfo() {

    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/events/{eventId}/tickets/checkout", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView purchaseTickets(
            @PathVariable("eventId") long id,
            CheckoutInfo checkoutInfo,
            RedirectAttributes redir,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        ......
    }
```

The null pointer exception occurs because checkoutInfo is null. I don't know why this could happen. I never seen this happen. And this only come from a few of our users. I am using spring boot v1.2.3.RELEASE

I appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: This is not necessarily a mistake. Maybe just some hackers, crawlers etc. sending wrong data. You can't really know if your client implementation didn't work or you really received illegal data.